# Sub-Routine POSIX path issue.

Tags: macos, unix, applescript

Working on a script that downloads files and places them in a folder for for automated installation. This is the first time I've created an "on" sub-routine and I'm having issues with resolving the path to check if the file exists. The process uses a Terminal window to monitor the download status.

```
    set theContentPath to POSIX path of (choose folder)
    set toInstall to (theContentPath & "ToInstall/")
    set inStalled to (theContentPath & "Installed/")
    set theTemp to (theContentPath & "theTemp/")
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of toInstall
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of inStalled
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of theTemp

    set theList to {"http://url1.pkg", 
    "http://url2.pkg", 
    "http://url3.pkg", 
    "http://url4.pkg", 
    "http://url5.pkg", 
    "http://url6.pkg"}

    repeat with x from 1 to (count theList)
        --display dialog item x of theList
        set thisOne to item x of theList
        getFileIfNeeded(thisOne, toInstall, theTemp)
    end repeat

    on getFileIfNeeded(theFileToGet, whereToSave, tempFiles)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
        set theItems to text items of theFileToGet
        set theFile to item 5 of theItems
        set theFileCheck to whereToSave & theFile
        set theURL to quoted form of theFileToGet
        tell application "Finder"
            if not (exists file theFileCheck) then
                tell application "Terminal"
                    if (count of windows) is 0 then
                        activate
                    end if
                    do script "cd " & quoted form of tempFiles & " ; curl -O " & theURL in front window
                    do script "mv  " & quoted form of tempFiles & "*.pkg " & quoted form of whereToSave in front window
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    end getFileIfNeeded
```

Tried adding the following `set theFileCheck2 to (POSIX file theFileCheck) as string` but the results are not what I expected as the file still get's downloaded.

Here's the routine with my attempt to get the path right.

```
     on getFileIfNeeded(theFileToGet, whereToSave, tempFiles)
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
            set theItems to text items of theFileToGet
            set theFile to item 5 of theItems
            set theFileCheck to whereToSave & theFile
            set theURL to quoted form of theFileToGet
            tell application "Finder"
                set theFileCheck2 to (POSIX file theFileCheck) as string
                if not (exists file theFileCheck2) then
                    tell application "Terminal"
                        if (count of windows) is 0 then
                            activate
                        end if
                        do script "cd " & quoted form of tempFiles & " ; curl -O " & theURL in front window
                        do script "mv  " & quoted form of tempFiles & "*.pkg " & quoted form of whereToSave in front window
                    end tell
                end if
            end tell
        end getFileIfNeeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it.

It targets "System Events" instead of "Finder", a lot of the functionality previously in the Finders dictionary has been shifted to System Events over the last several years.

Also i simplified the part that extracts *theFile*, you can use the 'last' keyword in this case instead of a hard coded number.

```
on getFileIfNeeded(theFileToGet, whereToSave, tempFiles)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
    set theFile to the last text item of theFileToGet
    set theFileCheck to whereToSave & theFile
    set theURL to quoted form of theFileToGet
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists file theFileCheck) then
            tell application "Terminal"
                if (count of windows) is 0 then
                    activate
                end if
                do script "cd " & quoted form of tempFiles & " ; curl -O " & theURL in front window
                do script "mv  " & quoted form of tempFiles & "*.pkg " & quoted form of whereToSave in front window
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
end getFileIfNeeded
```

Comment: Works as expected. Ran into another issue with a tell Finder call recently that was also resolved using System Events. So thanks for explaining the shift.